Is $\inf_{a \in A}\sup_{b \in B} \|a-b\|_H = \sup_{b \in B} \inf_{a \in A}\|a-b\|_H$?
Let $A \subset H$ be a closed and convex non-empty subset of a Hilbert space $H$. Let $B \subset H$ be bounded and non-empty (if necessarily closed as well).
Is it true that
$$\inf_{a \in A}\sup_{b \in B} \|a-b\|_H = \sup_{b \in B} \inf_{a \in A}\|a-b\|_H$$
i.e. can we interchange the $\inf$ and $\sup?$

Let $H$ be a one-dimensional (real or complex) Hilbert space and let $A=B$ be a closed line segment with positive length. Then the left hand side is half the length of the segment, while the right hand side is zero.

How to see that the LHS is half the length of the segment?

For fixed $a$ the supremum over all $b$ is the distance from $a$ to the furthest point on the line segment. If $a$ is not the exact middle of the segment then that point is the end point of that half of the segment that does not contain $a,$ which means its distance from $a$ is more than half of the length. Therefore the infimum over all $a$ is actually a minimum which is reached when $a$ is the middle of the segment.
